# entry edit no other content area unless title?

Tags: entries

I am a newbie of Craft CMS. I installed it on my localhost.

I added a few sections and fields to test it when I go to Entries, create and edit the entry, there is just a title input area?

Is that normal?

Or I need to add code in the backend files? I did not find a way to add it from the online documents.

[image]

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the fields to the section. 
If you go into Sections then over at the right side you can edit the entry type there. 
Drag the fields up to the top area to select the fields for that entry.

See https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sections-and-entries.html#entry-types

Comment: Finally, find it, thanks.